# Load a php file in a function call

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin. In the function call I want to load different PHP scripts. I tried using `include("filename.php")`.

The scenario is that a function is called in PHP for an Ajax post method. In this function I want to load a PHP file.

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work?

---

Update - Got it working by using include(/folder1/filename.php) no need to specify the whole
 path.

Comment: Not clear, could you paste the code of your ajax method and where you want to include the file?

Comment: did you set real path of filename.php ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for file inclusion (either by `include()` or `require()` )  should be:

```
include(dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/your-php-file.php');
```

if the file you want to include is in the same folder as your plugin's main file.